# How do I run a single ansible task with sudo -E?

Tags: sudo, ansible

I know I can run playbooks and tasks with sudo, but is there a way to run sudo with arguments? Specifically, I need to run `sudo -E <command>` to preserve the environment of the logged-in user.

If this is not possible, are there good workarounds?

---

**Edit**

Two clarifications:

1. I'm trying to run with `sudo -E` just for some tasks, not the whole playbook
2. A somewhat convoluted example of what I'm trying to do: I have an ubuntu EC2 instance where the `ubuntu` user has some hosts configured under `~/.ssh/config`.  I'd like to use those settings with the ansible git module without necessarily copying them into `/root/.ssh`, and I'd like to use them to modify a directory not owned by the `ubuntu` user. For pulling, for instance, one way to do this directly in the shell is to `sudo -E git pull`. An ideal solution would let me (1) use the ansible git module, (2) allow me to `sudo -E` for this task, and to `sudo` without the `-E` flag for other tasks.

Comment: what about `shell` and/or `sudo_user`?

Comment: @tedder42 can these be used for one task but not the whole playbook?

Comment: yes, `sudo_user` is put on a task, `shell` *is* a task. Give a sample task that shows what you want to do and we can try to help.

Answer (score 5):

just use `become_flags` at task level

```
become_flags: '-i'
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this via the [sudo_flags](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#sudo-flags) parameter in ansible.cfg

Comment: Can I use sudo_flags only for one task, but not the whole playbook?

Comment: I don't believe so, no. This is a setting in the configuration file, which is read only once at startup.

Comment: How about [ansible_become_method](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/become.html).